# Java Play2- Preventing CSRF

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, csrf

I saw https://github.com/orefalo/play2-authenticitytoken but this repository gives and 404 error and he closed the issue on his git
https://github.com/orefalo/play2-authenticitytoken/issues/4

Maybe it wasn't secure so he put it down?

- How do you currently prevent CSRF attacks in Play2?
- Or do I need to do it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the author behind the project you are referring.

The repo gives a 404 and that's perfectly fine, I don't want to get into the business of maintaining the artifact repository.

However the code is fully functional, just copy the contents of the project in your own project and you should be good to go.

Comment: I should, but I don't have time. plz submit a pull req. tks